# HTTP Status 403 when loading a CSS file from a secure domain (Rails 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I'm having an issue in Google Chrome regarding SSL. Basically my app is using a CSS file that is hosted on an SSL domain and served by a Rails 2 app. When I look into the Network tab, it shows a 403 status when loading the file. However, the file is loaded successfully when I open it in a new tab.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to get around it?